# Checking if file is 32bit or 64bit - on Windows

Tags: windows, x86, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm compiling a program on my 64bit machine, but I'm not sure if it produces 32-bit or 64-bit output.. How can I check if a file is 32bit or 64bit on Windows?

Comment: Linux, Windows, or ??? 
Solaris is already all 64 bit.

Comment: Sorry - windows.. Yeah, that was kinda essential..

Comment: For future answer seekers, this Windows Explorer extension allows you to view 32/64 bit architecture information inside your file manager without using external tool: http://sanje2v.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/writing-property-handler-for-windows-explorermanta-property-extension/ . Also supports DLL, LIB, OBJ, O and A files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [GNUfile](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) for windows.
You can run the app thru [PEID](http://www.peid.info/)
Lastly (and preferred- less room for error)
With either Visual Studio C++ (at least express edition minimum) or the [Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en) installed you can use dumpbin /headers to look at the PE header values.

The first value in the file header tells you the architecture: either 0x14C for x86 or 0x8664 for x64

Comment: Works fine! Didn't bother running it through PEID etc though. Ran with Cygwin. Works just fine. And it doesn't say 0x14C/0x86664, but PE32 for x86 and PE32+ for x64.

Answer (score 8):

Just run it and have a look at the Processes tab in Windows Task Manager. If there is a *32 suffix after the process name, it's 32-bit, otherwise it's 64-bit (provided you're on a 64-bit OS).

Comment: Well yes that'll work but it's not entirely sensible to just run a program to find out whether it's 32 or 64 bit. Also, you may not have a 64 bit machine to do that with.

Comment: if you only have a 32bit machine then it would not run if it was a 64bit app!

Answer (score 2):

You could run the 'file' command from linux in a cygwin environment to test.

You could also place some debug statement like 'print sizeof(int)' (schematically) to check.

Comment: Sounds like a terrific idea. I'm running Cygwin, but when I try using "file" it says "command not found". Is this actually available on Cygwin? If so I guess I must've forgotten to install some package..?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [EXE Explorer](http://www.mitec.cz/exe.html) by MiTec, a small free tool. It also displays many other properites of the binary file it checks.

I had the same question as the original poster and the [EXE Explorer](http://www.mitec.cz/exe.html) works for me quite well.

Answer (score 0):

http://ntinfo.biz/ - Detect It Easy.

Or just GNU Binutils `objdump -f my.exe`